# Raspberry Pi wont remove OpenElec and Kodi

Tags: operating-system, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, kodi, openelec

I have gotten a used Raspberry Pi 3 Model B (bought used).
I formatted the SD-Card and downloaded [Raspbian Stretch Lite](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/). When I turned on the Pi, somehow it opened [Openelec](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/OpenELEC) with [Kodi](https://www.wikiwand.com/de/Kodi_(Software)).
I tried it again and again. I went and tried to install [NOOBS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/) instead. Same thing happens. It opens OpenELEC and Kodi.

I have formatted the SD-Card using a Windows 10 PC. Triied it with the "Quick formating" option on and off. After formating, the SD-Card seems to be empty, as far as I can tell from Windows explorer.

Since I dont really need the GUI, it wouldnt be so bad when I could just use ssh to get a terminal and do the work I want to do. However, Openelec disabled basic things like apt-get. When I try it, the following message appears:

```
There is no working 'apt-get'.
 'apt-get' is a command to install, update and remove software which
 is stored in a non local repo. 'apt-get' does nothing then connecting to such
 repo, downloads the software, unpacks the software, updates a big
 local database with all filepaths and other informations about the
 installed software or removes or updates installed Software.

 With OpenELEC it is not possible to change the system for security and
 stability reasons so even 'apt-get' would not be able to do this.
 We also dont have and want to maintain such a repo for various other
 great reasons.

 Also Ubuntu or Debian packages are often outdated and not compatible
 with OpenELEC

 TIP: use XBMC's addon browser to enhance your OpenELEC system
```

I cant exmplain that behaviour. To my knowledge, the Pi should not have any type of internal storage. So I dont understand how the old OS can still be there after I format the SD-Card for the 5th time (no other data storage medium connected). Noobs and Raspbian shouldnt have anything to do with Kodi or Openelec so I do not undestand how it keeps coming up. I have tried to look for a solution online but couldnt find anything but how to install the software that I want to get rid of.

Does anybody know how I can remove Openelec and Kodi so that I can have a normal Raspbian distribution installed? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You formatted the microSD card on your PC and it still boots into Openelec?  Did you write the Raspbian Lite image onto the card?  It seems that you haven't actually modified the contents of the card.

I strongly recommend getting Etcher to write bootable images; you don't even have to decompress the downloaded image, Etcher will do that for you.  Etcher is pretty smart at figuring out which media is your microSD card, but as always when working with tools that can overwrite disks **be careful.**

Comment: This sounds right. The question states they "downloaded" Noobs and Raspbian, nothing about ever actually installing the images onto the SD card for booting the Pi.

Comment: Other readers of this question should note that Raspberry Pi SD Cards have TWO partitions, typically.  The first is an MS-DOS/FAT partition that holds the boot programs, the second is a Linux ext4 (typically) partition that holds the Linux system.  In Raspbian, the ext4 partition is mounted on /, the FAT partition on /boot.